# Trigger an EAGAIN on a socket receiving on another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, tcp

Say that I have two threads, the main thread and a thread that is dedicated to continuously listening on a standard TCP socket. Now, say that at some point I want to shutdown everything. From the main thread, I would like to close the connection the listening thread is working on, then join the thread and end the program.

However, this is tricky, since I don't know how to make the listening thread return from the call to `read`. That call won't return unless something actually is received, and in principle I could be waiting for a long long time until the other endpoint decides to send me something.

When I was working with UDP sockets, I used to work around this problem by sending a packet on that port from my loopback interface, therefore triggering a return from `recvfrom`. However, this is terribly inelegant and it cannot be done on a TCP socket.

I know that another workaround could be to set a timeout with `setsockopt`: in this way I am guaranteed that the call will eventually return, but this is inelegant as well, and also quite inefficient since I could be waiting for several seconds before being able to join the thread.

So I was wondering if there is some way to trigger an `EAGAIN` on a socket `read` call, not unlike the one I would get on a timeout, so that on my main thread I could just call some `force_return`on my socket descriptor and the call to `read` on the other thread would return?

Comment: Wouldn't `recv` return immediately with error if the socket that is being listened on was closed in another thread? Is using `O_NONBLOCK` an option?

Comment: Is your TCP thread listening/accepting as you say in your first sentence, reading on an established connection as you say in paragraph two, or both?

Comment: Whops. Sorry. I misused my words. I am talking about reading from a connection which was already established.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to join a thread that is hanging on blocking IO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203754/how-to-join-a-thread-that-is-hanging-on-blocking-io)

Answer (score 3):

I usually solve this problem by creating a [`pipe`()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pipe) and using [`select()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/select) in the reading thread. The reading thread must select on both the TCP socket and one end of the pipe. Whenever you want to shut down the reader, set a flag and write some data to the other end of the pipe.

Setup:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int signalPipe[2];

...

pipe(signalPipe);
```

Reader:

```
while(running)
{
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(tcpSocket, &fds);
    FD_SET(signalPipe[0], &fds);
    select(max(tcpSocket, signalPipe[0]) + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    ...
}
```

Other thread:

```
// We want to stop now.
running = false;
write(signalPipe[1], "foo", 3);
```